# Lightning Console

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, console

Is it possible to identify whether loggedIn user is viewing lightning component in console or not? In classic, we have isConsole() method, do we have similar method in lightning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `isConsoleNavigation()` for Lightning Experience.

> `isConsoleNavigation()` Determines whether the app it’s used within
>   uses console navigation.

Markup:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <lightning:workspaceAPI aura:id="workspace" />
    <lightning:button label="Is Console Navigation?" onclick="{! c.isConsoleNavigation }" />
</aura:component>
```

JS:

```
({
    isConsoleNavigation : function(component, event, helper) {
        var workspaceAPI = component.find("workspace");
        workspaceAPI.isConsoleNavigation().then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
})
```

Src: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_lightning_isConsoleNavigation.htm